# Complete sequence between a range in python

Tags: python, sequence

I have a range that is decided (e.g., 0 to 14). I have a list of list with at least one sequence as a sublist already in the list of list in ascending order (e.g., [[6, 7], [10, 11, 12]]). I need a function that completes the sequence from 0 to 14 with the already included sequences intact. For the running example, the output list of list should be [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6,7], [8], [9], [10, 11, 12], [13], [14]]. What is the most Pythonic way to do this?

```
def complete_seq(range, listoflist):
     return new_listoflist

completed_list = complete_seq((0, 14), [[6, 7], [10, 11, 12]])
```

Comment: Have you tried anything already?

Comment: Sounds you are only seeking to fill those missinge item, but not in `range`?

Comment: I have tried to create sequences from 0-5 and 8-9 and then combine those ranges with the existing ones. But that seems like a messy approach. I am looking for any suggestions, maybe using a library like Itertools @DrPrettyman

Comment: @DanielHao Yes, I am looking to complete the sequence in the range (0 to 14). But I need to preserve the grouping ([6,7] and [10, 11, 12]) that is already there in the input list of list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sets are *probably* the most Pythonic way to do this. The sorting at the end converts non-list elements into lists for the sake of comparison.

```
>>> def complete_seq(r, lsts):
...   # The set of all of the numbers we need.
...   s = set(range(r[0], r[1]+1))
...   # The set of all of the numbers already accounted for in lsts.
...   s2 = {y for x in lsts for y in x}
...   # The set of numbers not present in lsts.
...   s3 = s - s2
...   # A list composed of the other numbers and the lists in lsts.
...   lst = [*s3, *lsts]
...   # Sort, converting just numbers into lists so they can be compared to the lists in lsts.
...   return sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x if isinstance(x, list) else [x])
... 
>>> complete_seq((0, 14), [[6,7], [10, 11, 12]])
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [6, 7], 8, 9, [10, 11, 12], 13, 14]
```

Answer (score 1):

This'll do the trick:

```py
def complete_seq(_range, listoflist):
    current_sub_list_index = 0
    current_sub_list = listoflist[current_sub_list_index]
    new_listoflist = []
    i = _range[0]
    while i <= _range[1]:
        if i not in current_sub_list:
            new_listoflist.append([i])
            i += 1
        else:
            new_listoflist.append(current_sub_list)
            i = current_sub_list[-1] + 1
            current_sub_list_index += 1
            if current_sub_list_index < len(listoflist):
                current_sub_list = listoflist[current_sub_list_index]
            else:
                current_sub_list = []
    return new_listoflist
```

I've separated the process out a bit for clarity, you might be able to golf this code